# Creating a linked title inside a linked div

Tags: html, css

I'd like to create a full-width header div that links to the top of the page and inside this div, there is the 'page title' that links to the home page.

Doing so, doesn't seem to work: https://jsfiddle.net/9wscc5yy/

```
<a href="www.example.com">
<div id="header" style="width:100%; background-color: #fff">
  <a href="www.google.com">www.google.com
  </a>
</div>
</a>
```

So I tried to create three divs next to each other with the middle div containing the 'page title' and the remaining two divs floating left and right. The result: https://jsfiddle.net/vef0tt07/

```
<div id="header">

  <a href="www.example.com">
  <div style="float: left; width: 40%; background-color:#fff">
  &nbsp;
  </div>
  </a>

  <a href="www.example.com">
  <div style="float: right; width: 40%; background-color:#fff">
  &nbsp;
  </div>
  </a>

  <a href="www.google.com">
  <div style="overflow:hidden; text-align: center;">
  <strong>Title</strong>
  </div>
  </a>

</div>
```

The new issue is that I don't know how to let the side divs change width so that they always reach to the text of the 'page title'.

Is there a better way to create a linked title inside a linked div?

Thanks in advance for your time to help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

**HTML**

```
<header>
    <h1>
        <a href="http://www.dell.com">link to top of page</a>
    </h1>
    <h2>
        <a href="http://www.google.com">link to home page</a>
    </h2>
</header>
```

**CSS**

```
header {
    position: relative;
    background-color: red;
    height: 50px;
}

h1 {
    margin: 0;
}

h1 > a {
    display: block;
    color: red;
}

h2 {
    margin: 0;
    background-color: yellow;
    position: absolute; 
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/ae9ghq94/1/)

The background section (red) links to one place. The title in the middle (yellow) links to another place.

With absolute positioning, the `h2` is set to remain perfectly centered in the `header`.

---

**Update** (based on comments)

In order to make the header fully responsive, with no artificial heights, and  all links equal height regardless of content size, use [**flexbox**](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

It's actually very simple and requires minimal code.

**HTML**

```
<header>
    <a href="#"></a>
    <a href="#"></a>
    <a href="#"></a>
</header>
```

**CSS**

```
header { display: flex; }  /* establish flex container */
header > a { flex: 1; }    /* make all flex items equal width */
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/ae9ghq94/4/)

---

*To learn more about flexbox visit:*

- [Using CSS flexible boxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) ~ MDN
- [A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) ~ CSS-Tricks

---

*Note that flexbox is supported by all major browsers, [except IE 8 & 9](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex). Some recent browser versions, such as Safari 8 and IE10, require [vendor prefixes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix). For a quick way to add all the prefixes you need, post your CSS in the left panel here: [Autoprefixer](https://autoprefixer.github.io/).*

Comment: Thank you very much, that's a very clever solution. It's only flaw seems to be that the height does not wrap around the title, e.g. with a long title string that might break into two lines on mobile devices.

Comment: No flaw. Just add a *media query*. See [**revised demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/ae9ghq94/3/) ;-)

Comment: I apologise as I shouldn't have called it a flaw, it's indeed more an undefined property. I'm quite happy with your initial solution. I didn't mention that the title is different for each page, so that the media query's max-width treshold cannot be a fixed pre-calculated value. I think that the header div's 'height:auto' should correspond to the 'h2 height', but that's doesn't seem to work

Comment: Your help and thorough explanation are much appreciated. Although the flexbox method comes the closest to what I'd like to achieve and appears to be very neat, the center 'Home Page Link' is superfluous in width on wider screens. And as I understand the concept of 'flex', their width is always in relation to other flexboxes.
I'm very satisfied with your assistance. but feel that I'm bothering you too much with nitpicking. ^^

Comment: No problem. Happy to help. The width of each flex item can be specified independently and with precision. That's not a problem. What's the result you want?

Comment: I want your flexbox demo with the central 'flexbox' having a max-width that equals the string length. i.e. the yellow box should never extend further than the first nor last letter of the title 'Home Page Link'.
Or similarly, your initial answer with the possibility for a very long title that doesn't protrude outside it's div.
Is my description accurate and clear?

Comment: To control the size of each flex item (the child elements in a flexbox), you can use the [**flex**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) property. By applying [**`flex: none`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-common) to the middle item, its width is governed solely by the content size. [**Revised Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/ae9ghq94/5/).

Comment: Yes, that's perfect! Thank you once again ^^